# why doesn't this python-like ruby script work?

Tags: python, ruby, scope

I'm kind of confused about how scoping works in Ruby. Which Ruby scoping rules prevent the following code from printing out the value of x?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

x = 5
def test
    puts "x = #{x}"
end

test    # => undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object
```

The equivalent Python script does print the value of x:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

x = 5
def test():
    print "x = %s" % x

test()  # => x = 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "[Ruby classes, include, and scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7549843/502458)" for more information about Ruby's scoping and scope gating.

There are a few ways to provide visibility to your test function. One is to make the variable an instance variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

@x = 5
def test
    puts "x = #{@x}"
end
```

And another is to use a closure with lambda:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

x = 5
test = lambda do
    puts "x = #{x}"
end

test.call
```

or Proc.new()

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

x = 5
test = Proc.new do
    puts "x = #{x}"
end

test.call
```

For the differences between lambda and Proc.new, see "[When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/723/502458)".

Answer (score 5):

This is so called "scope gate". There are three gates in ruby: definition of a method, a class or a module. Meaning that inside that definition locals from outer scope are not visible.

This is so because when scope changes, current set of bindings gets replaced by a new set of bindings and cannot be easily accessed.

See "[Metaprogramming Ruby: Program Like the Ruby Pros](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby)" for more information.

Comment: The new version of this book is [Metaprogramming Ruby 2: Program Like the Ruby Pros](https://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby)